# NSString by removing the initial zeros?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

How can I remove leading zeros from an `NSString`?

e.g. I have:

`NSString  *myString;`

with values such as `@"0002060"`, `@"00236"` and `@"21456"`.

I want to remove any leading zeros if they occur:

e.g. Convert the previous to `@"2060"`, `@"236"` and `@"21456"`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**For smaller numbers:**

```
NSString *str = @"000123";      
NSString *clean = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [str intValue]];
```

**For numbers exceeding int32 range:**

```
NSString *str = @"100004378121454";     
NSString *clean = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [str longLongValue]];
```

Comment: Hi @adali, but when the string length is >9, it gives some different value.Can you pls check it.For e.g. NSString *str = @"3103282369";      
    NSString *clean = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [str intValue]];
    NSLog(@"Clean- %@",clean); gives 2147483647 as output.

Comment: oh, because it overflow the range of the int value  , ni can change it to longLongValue , then you must format it to  %qi instead of %d

Comment: and if the number is too large  you may use the solution below :)

Comment: the range of int is –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647   and the range of long is –9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807  , check if it is enough for you

Answer (score 18):

This is actually a case that is perfectly suited for regular expressions:

```
NSString *str = @"00000123";

NSString *cleaned = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"^0+"              
                                                   withString:@"" 
                                                      options:NSRegularExpressionSearch 
                                                        range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
```

Only one line of code (in a logical sense, line breaks added for clarity) and there are no limits on the number of characters it handles.

A brief explanation of the regular expression pattern:

The `^` means that the pattern should be anchored to the beginning of the string. We need that to ensure it doesn't match legitimate zeroes inside the sequence of digits.

The `0+` part means that it should match one or more zeroes.

Put together, it matches a sequence of one or more zeroes at the beginning of the string, then replaces that with an empty string - i.e., it deletes the leading zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

```
 - (NSString *) removeLeadingZeros:(NSString *)Instring
 {
        NSString *str2 =Instring ;

        for (int index=0; index<[str2 length]; index++) 
        {
           if([str2 hasPrefix:@"0"]) 
               str2  =[str2 substringFromIndex:1];
            else
                break;
        }
        return str2;

 }
```

Comment: Your original code was just missing a return statement before the recursive call to removeLeadingZeros.

Answer (score 1):

The following method also gives the output.

```
NSString *test = @"0005603235644056";

// Skip leading zeros
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:test];
NSCharacterSet *zeros = [NSCharacterSet
                         characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0"];
[scanner scanCharactersFromSet:zeros intoString:NULL];

// Get the rest of the string and log it
NSString *result = [test substringFromIndex:[scanner scanLocation]];
NSLog(@"%@ reduced to %@", test, result);
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to adali's answer, you can do the following if you're worried about the string being too long (i.e. greater than 9 characters):

```
NSString *str = @"000200001111111";
NSString *strippedStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld", [temp longLongValue]];
```

This will give you the result: 200001111111

Otherwise, `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [temp intValue]]` will probably return 2147483647 because of overflow.