# Replace "0" with blank character in String

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `NSString` like `@"05205"` or `@"05931"` or so.
I want to remove the leading 0 characters.

E.g. `@"05205"` in `@"5205"` or `@"00072"` in `@"72"`.

How can I achieve this in Objective-C?

Comment: I think you mean to say that you want to remove leading `0` characters.

Comment: have you at least try to read NSString doc?

Comment: Where are you getting these?  If form a format operation then you can fix that.  Otherwise, NSString documents several different ways to remove/blank characters.

Comment: i use a pickerview with 5 numbers and yes i want to remove leading 0 characters :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you convert the string to an integer and then back to a string, it will trim the leading zeros.

```
NSString *s = @"0072";
NSString *newString =[ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[s integerValue]];
```

Comment: +1 clever solution. You can make it even shorter, even though probably less efficient `@(@"0042".integerValue).stringValue`

Comment: woooow the answer is perfect !!! :D genius !!

Comment: I like the answer, but I'd probably go with the widest available type like `%lld` and `[s longLongValue]` (or the unsigned equiv if he knows the values will always be positive)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10530899/312312

Answer (score 7):

With the `NSStringCompareOptions` `NSAnchoredSearch`, the search is limited to the start of the string, so you can use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:` this way:

```
NSString* str= @"0072";
str= [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"0"
                                    withString:@""
                                       options:NSAnchoredSearch
                                         range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
```

Comment: This is the better, more general answer than the neat trick by rdelmar.

Comment: yep, really nice. It's basically the equivalent of the `dropWhile` function in <insert functional programming language at will>