# Most efficient way to remove leading zeros from Swift string

Tags: swift, substring, leading-zero

I have a string such as "00123456" that I would like to have in an string "123456", with the leading zeros removed.

I've found [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530873/nsstring-by-removing-the-initial-zeros) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354933/nsstring-remove-leading-0s-so-00001234-becomes-1234) for Objective-C but not sure best way to do so with Swift.

Comment: Good question! Moreover, to check this you have to testify with CPU time in async.main queue

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just convert the string to an int and then back to a string again. It will remove the leading zeros.

```
let numberString = "00123456"
let numberAsInt = Int(numberString)
let backToString = "\(numberAsInt!)"
```

Result: "123456"

Comment: Be careful here with the forced unwrap: make sure that the String is not empty ("") i.e. with a guard statement. Otherwise this code will crash.

Comment: In this case the string is defined so it will never be nil. But yes, if the string is dynamic you would have to handle it to guard for a nil value.

Comment: if the resulting number is too big this will fail.

Comment: why is this marked correct, it's obviously not the right type safe decision.

Comment: Be careful with this implementation. I used it for a production code and it crushed because some user entered a number that exceeds the Int64 limit. `Int(numberString)` was nil in this case, and force-unwrapping caused a crash

Answer (score 46):

You can do that with Regular Expression

```
let string = "00123456"
let trimmedString = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "^0+", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

The benefit is no double conversion and no force unwrapping.

Update:

This works also with negative numbers

```
let trimmedString = string.replacingOccurrences(of: #"^([+-])?0+"#, with: "$1", options: .regularExpression)
```

or with Swift Regex (available in Swift 5.7+)

```
let trimmedString = string.replacing(/^([+-])?0+/, with: {$0.output.1 ?? ""})
```

Comment: This should be an excepted answer.

Comment: Does not work if the number is negative

Comment: @ratkevich Please see the update.

Answer (score 0):

First, create Validator then use it in any class. 
This is an example and it works :) 
This is swift 4.0

```
class PhoneNumberExcludeZeroValidator {
    func validate(_ value: String) -> String {
        var subscriberNumber = value
        let prefixCase = "0"
        if subscriberNumber.hasPrefix(prefixCase) {
            subscriberNumber.remove(at: subscriberNumber.startIndex)
        }
        return subscriberNumber
    }
}
```

example for usage:

```
if let countryCallingCode = countryCallingCodeTextField.text, var subscriberNumber = phoneNumberTextField.text {

     subscriberNumber = PhoneNumberExcludeZeroValidator().validate(subscriberNumber)

          let phoneNumber = "\(countryCallingCode)\(subscriberNumber)"
          registerUserWith(phoneNumber: phoneNumber)
}
```

Comment: This only removes first 0. If someone enters 0011234 then it will be like: 011234

Answer (score -2):

```
let number = "\(String(describing: Int(text)!))"
```

Comment: Why not simply `"\(Int(text)!)"` or `String(Int(text)!)`? Creating a string from a string with String Interpolation is redundant.